# Both blocking and non blocking queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-thread

I need to set up a producer-consumer scheme with two threads linked by a queue (the producer pushing tasks into the queue, the consumer executing them as they come).

Since the queue will be empty most of the time I must make it so that the consumer thread can sleep and be woken up as soon as something is pushed by the producer. However I must ensure that the producer is never blocked, not even shortly. In other words, I need some one-sided blocking queue.

There are lock free queues, but since those are by definition, well, lock free, it isn't possible for the consumer thread to be blocked by them.

I have thought of associating a lock free queue with a condition variable. When the consumer thread finds the queue empty it would sleep waiting for the condition to be notified. The producer thread would notify the condition when pushing a task into the queue waking up the consumer thread (if it was sleeping). However, condition variable must be protected by mutex, that mean there is still a small chance for the producer thread to be blocked when trying to acquire it to notify the condition.

I have yet to find a really good way to solve this problem so your ideas are more then welcome.

Note : I'm planning to use boost thread to implement this.

Note 2 : I'm not considering the case where the producer trys to push something and the queue is full. This is never going to happen.

Comment: `boost` lockfree queues **can** be blocking, you can just use that.

Comment: Fwiw, the mutex in a cvar/mtx pair isn't to protect the condition variable; it's to protect the *predicate data*. Worth mentioning because there is no need for the producer to latch the mutex before signaling the cvar. Your predicate state (queue condition) is lock-free. The consumer would obviously need to unlatch the mutex immediately upon waking, but thats really all there would be to it.

Comment: What happens to producer when it wants to post but the queue is full?

Comment: @quantdev : as far as I can tell from the doc, both boost::lockfree::spsc_queue and boost::lockfree::queue pod() method return immediately no matter if something was popped or not. So I don't see how I can block the consumer thread with these. Did I misunderstand something ?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin : I consider this case will never happen.

Comment: @WhozCraig : it appears you're right. The producer thread doesn't need to lock the mutex to notify the condition, therefore it is never going to be blocked. I will test this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[tbb](/questions/tagged/tbb) library [provides](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download) both blocking and non-blocking queues:

- [tbb::concurrent_queue<>](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm) provides non-blocking `try_pop()` and `push()` for unlimited growth.
- [tbb::concurrent_bounded_queue<>](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_bounded_queue_cls.htm) provides `push()` which can block if  capacity limit is specified and when it is reached; and `pop()` which waits for items in empty queue. It also provides non-blocking `try_push()` and `try_pop()` alternatives for the same queue.

Comment: I think the OP needs a single data structure supporting both of blocking and non-blocking operations